# Openpyxl Version 2.4.5 TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am going through the excercises at [Automate the Boring Stuff](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/),
which uses openpyxl 2.3.3 while the version I am using is 2.4.5

and am stuck here:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.columns[1]
```

at which point I hit this error:

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
>>> sheet = wb.active
>>> sheet.columns[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is this because there is something wrong with my commands, or because I am using a different version and sheet.columns now has different syntax?

The excel sheet I am using is simple and has a1:c:7 filled in with data. 
a column being dates, b column being strings, and c column being integers.

Thanks

Comment: The error is telling you that `wb.active.columns` is a _generator_ not a list. Are you sure the example given my ATBS indexed the `.columns` attribute?

Comment: Here it is copy and pasted - >>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
>>> sheet = wb.active
>>> sheet.columns[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.columns), `sheet.columns` is an iterator over the columns in the worksheet.

You can either convert that to a list and index that:

```
columns = list(wb.active.columns)
```

Or if you just want that single column, you could just iterate to it:

```
next(next(sheet.columns))
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick, not sure it the tutorial was a type-o or if I was missing a key piece of information.

Comment: Possibly the tutorial was using a version in which that attribute was not a generator.

Comment: That is most likely the reason as there were previous instances where the syntax was different for 2.4.5 than the 2.3.3 version the tutorial uses.

Answer (score 3):

The updated and working example  should be:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

sheet = wb.active

columnas = list(sheet)

for i in range(len(columnas)):
    print(columnas[i][0].value)
```